# Which coding system should I use in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, character-encoding

I have just tried to save a simple *.rtf file with some websites and tips on how to use emacs and I got

> These default coding systems were
>   tried to encode text in the buffer
>   `notes.rtf':   (iso-latin-1-dos (315 .
>   8216) (338 . 8217) (1514 . 8220) (1525
>   . 8221)) However, each of them
>   encountered characters it couldn't
>   encode:   iso-latin-1-dos cannot
>   encode these: ‘ ’ “ ”
>   ....
>   etc, etc, etc

Now what is that? Now it is asking me to chose an encoding system

> Select coding system (default
>   chinese-iso-8bit):

I don't even know what an encoding system is, and I would rather not have to choose one every time I try and save a document... Is there any way I can set an encoding system that will work with all my files so I don't have to worry about this?

I saw another question and asnswer elsewhere in this website ([see it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785200/change-emacs-default-coding-system)) and it seems that if I type the following

> (defun set-coding-system () (setq
>   buffer-file-coding-system
>   'utf-8-unix)) (add-hook
>   'find-file-hook 'set-coding-system)

then I can have Emacs do this, but I am not sure... Can someone confirm this to me?

Comment: Nothing is simple in Emacs -- that's lesson 1.

Comment: ha, I realise that. When I told the PhD coordinator I was trying to learn Emacs he said: Emacs is a life choice. I agreed and said that if I am to make a life choice, there is no time better than now. But yeah, things are pretty hard. Only yesterday I found one person in the department who uses Emacs, but unfortunately I can't expect him (or anyone) to sit down with me for hours to make it work. This site has been a great help  :) Hopefully one day I will be able to help others the same way others have been helping me!

Comment: Agreed -- and I applaud you for that.  I could only make that remark because I just made the same life choice.  But I'm about to be a father, too, so we'll see what takes precedence :)

Comment: A kid: now *that* is a life choice! Best of luck for you and your kid-in-the-oven  :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Here's a pretty comprehensive group of magic invocations to make Emacs use UTF-8 everywhere by default:

```
  (setq utf-translate-cjk-mode nil) ; disable CJK coding/encoding (Chinese/Japanese/Korean characters)
  (set-language-environment 'utf-8)
  (set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8-mac) ; For old Carbon emacs on OS X only
  (setq locale-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
  (set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (set-selection-coding-system
    (if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
        'utf-16-le  ;; https://rufflewind.com/2014-07-20/pasting-unicode-in-emacs-on-windows
      'utf-8))
  (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
```

Comment: On Windows, it's best to avoid `(set-selection-coding-system 'utf-8)` as it alters the clipboard behavior in Emacs.  The correct value for `selection-coding-system` (aka `clipboard-coding-system`) on Windows should be `'utf-16-le` (the default) in order to allow Emacs to cooperate with other Unicode programs.

Comment: Running emacs in a linux VM and copying in text from Windows, the unless function (two lines) will cause the text to appear as Chinese... if you leave set-selection-coding-system as nil, Emacs will try to interpret the data according to what is on the clipboard, which I think is generally better.

Answer (score 8):

You should use [UTF8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF8); it can handle all the characters you'll ever need

Comment: So if I put

(defun set-coding-system () (setq buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)) (add-hook 'find-file-hook 'set-coding-system)

in my .emacs file will my problem be solved?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't even set the coding system now. When I try to answer the question about the coding system it says: "text is read only"  :(  I have never felt so computer illiterate as now.

Comment: OK, I found a good answer:   
Q: "How to permanently choose a encoding system in emacs for opening and saving?" ->
A: "Choose the menu “Options‣Mule (Multilingual Environment)‣Set Language Environment”. After that, be sure to pull the menu “Options‣Save Options” to save the setting in your emacs init file."

Yay! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it can complement Vivi's comments on SLacks's answer, about "How to permanently choose a encoding system in emacs for opening and saving?", here is a way to choose the coding system permanently and just for one file :
Write `-*- coding: NAME OF THE CODING SYSTEM -*-` at the very top of the file, where you have to specify 'NAME OF THE CODING SYSTEM'.

You can find the name of a coding system by typing `M-x list-coding-systems <RET>`. Information about a coding system can be obtained by typing `C-h C NAME OF THE CODING SYSTEM <RET>`.

All I mention here is explained in the Emacs Manual, of course.

Note that you can set the mode for a specific file the same way as the coding system, just put `-*- mode: NAME OF THE MODE -*-` at the top of the file.